# Java Swing query

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a Swing Panel where I search for a text and highlight it using yellow color.Its size is 1/4th of the screen(not sure of exact dimensions).When I search soemthing the first active search is highlighted and shown and whenever I maxmize the screen to full size the highlighted text is not visible.Now is there a way to keep the highlighted text visible all the time irrespective of whether I maximize or minimize the Panel

Comment: That's actually so vaguely described that I have no clue what exactly you're doing there and what might be the cause.

Comment: You should mention the specific swing components that you are using (that are related to your question). JTextField? JList? JTree? JTextArea? JPanel?

Comment: I am leaving for the week.I will update on Monday and sorry for the description.Apologies

Comment: I think the OP wants to scroll the textfield in a way that keeps the highlighted text visible onscreen during resizes.

Comment: If you want to include some screen shots of what you're encountering, I recommend tinypic.com for hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=16674